# How to break a single command inside a `script` step on multiple lines

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

We have a project using Azure Pipeline, relying on `azure-pipelines.yml` file at the repo's root.

When implementing a `script` step, it is possible to execute successive commands in the same step simply writing them on different lines:

```
- script: |
  ls -la
  pwd
  echo $VALUE
```

Yet, if we have a single command that is very long, we would like to be able to break it on several lines in the YAML file, but cannot find the corresponding syntax?

Comment: Hi @Ad N Did you try out below answer, Did it work for you? Please let me know if there is any question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, the only way we found for to break a single command on multiple line is using *YAML folded style*:

```
- script: >
    echo
    'hello world'
```

It is all about replacing `|` with `>`.

Notes:

- It is **not** possible to introduce extra indentation on the following lines! For example, trying to align all arguments given to a command would break the behaviour.
- This style will replace newlines in the provided value with a simple white space. This means the script now can only contain **a single command** (maybe adding literal `\n` at the end of the line would actually introduce a linebreak in the string, but it feels backward compared to the usual approach of automatice linebreak unless an explicit continuation is added).

Comment: Hi @Ad N Since you worked it out using yaml folded style `>`. You can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 10):

You didn't specify your agent OS so I tested on both `windows-latest` and `ubuntu-latest`. Note that the script task runs a bit differently on these 2 environments. On Windows, it uses cmd.exe. On Ubuntu, it uses bash. Therefore, you have to use the correct syntax.

On Windows:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- script: |
    mkdir ^
    test ^
    -p ^
    -v
```

On Ubuntu:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- script: |
    mkdir \
    test \
    -p \
    -v
```

Those two files above work on my Azure DevOps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Then we assume this syntax is actually forwarded to the underlying shell which does the interpretation. Sadly, since we heavily rely on matrix builds spanning Windows and Linux/macOS, we cannot rely on a different syntax depending on underlying agent OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use '^' to break your command line into multiple lines. Check below exmaple. Below script will output 'hello world' like a single line command echo 'hello world'

```
- script: |
    echo ^
    'hello ^
    world'
```

Comment: I was able to test just now, and as far as I can tell, the script still considers each line as an individual command, thus breaking the expected behaviour.