# Is it possible to call a Test task from the powershell loop you created in Azure Pipelines

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to call a Test task from the PowerShell loop you created:

```
foreach ($i in ${{parameters.files}})
 - task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'VsTest - testPlan'
  inputs:
    testSuite: '$i'
    testConfiguration: '$(testConfig)'
```

Because when I tried to use:

```
- ${{ each item in parameters.files }}:
- task: VSTest@2
      displayName: 'VsTest - testPlan'
      inputs:
        testSuite: '$item'
        testConfiguration: '$(testConfig)'
```

it does not work as the and gets an error: `Unexpected Values`

Trying to use same pipelines looping logic from the link below:
[How to use output of a powershell command as parameters in Azure pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59425275/how-to-use-output-of-a-powershell-command-as-parameters-in-azure-pipeline/62488923#62488923)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can refer to the current variable with `${{ variable }}`, for example:

```
- ${{ each item in parameters.files }}:
- task: VSTest@2
      displayName: 'VsTest - testPlan'
      inputs:
        testSuite: '${{ item }}'
        testConfiguration: '$(testConfig)'
```

Comment: - ${{ each item in parameters.files }}:                                                                                       Is not working as it shows error reading parameters. Expected a sequence or mapping. Actual value '$(Filename) '
 files.testSuite: '${{ item }}' shows null.                                                   
But it works fine when i loop them using power shell.