# Unexpected EOF - Terraform apply

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform

I am new to Azure / Azure Devops and Terraform, I am getting the following error when im running terraform apply from an Azure DevOps Pipeline.

/home/vsts/work/_temp/38418e2b-b5e5-48c1-8579-69d937b85bfc.sh: line 9: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/home/vsts/work/_temp/38418e2b-b5e5-48c1-8579-69d937b85bfc.sh: line 10: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Here is the script I am trying to execute as part of a yaml pipeline. I can run the same code for UAT and Prod with no issues.

```
      - script: |
                terraform apply \
                  -auto-approve \
                  -var="client-id=$(client-id)" \
                  -var="client-secret=$(client-secret)" \
                  -var="subscription-id=$(subscription-id)" \
                  -var="tenant-id=$(tenant-id)" \
                  -var="application_name=transport" \
                  -var="environment_tag=dev" \
                  -var="location=northeurope" \
        workingDirectory: './deploy'
        displayName: 'Terraform apply'
```

Comment: You have a trailing line continutation `\\` at the end of your inline script.

Comment: @Daniel. Thanks for your reply, I have tried removing that and running it but it still throws the same error.

Comment: Hi @MattS Did you try below answer? How did it go?

Comment: Hi @Levi, Thanks for taking the time to reply. I was running this on an Ubuntu agent. 

I worked out that there must have been a character within the client-secret that what causing the script to fail.
I generated the client secret again and the error has now gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've generated a new client secret this morning and the script is running fine. I guess there was character within the last secret causing this to error.
I cannot explain why the Terraform init part for the script was able to execute correctly as this was also using the same secret.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on a Windows agent. You can try use '^'. For below example

```
 - script: |
      terraform apply ^
         -auto-approve ^
         -var="client-id=$(client-id)" ^
          ....
```

You can also try replacing '|' with '>'.

```
- script: >
    terraform apply \
      -auto-approve \
      -var="client-id=$(client-id)" \
```

Please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59198459/how-to-break-a-single-command-inside-a-script-step-on-multiple-lines) for more information.